# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:

Tags: java, save, javafx

I'm trying to load application data with text from a file using `loadPlayerDataFromFile` method:

```
public void loadPlayerDataFromFile(File file) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("player", Player.class);

    try {
        String xml = FileUtil.readFile(file);

        ArrayList<Player> playerList = (ArrayList<Player>) xstream
                .fromXML(xml);

        playerData.clear();
        playerData.addAll(playerList);

        setPlayerFilePath(file);
    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception                        
         Dialogs.showErrorDialog(primaryStage,
         "Could not load data from file:\n" + file.getPath(),
         "Could not load data", "Error", e);             
    }
}
public File getPlayerFilePath() {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(GameApp.class);
    prefs.put( "playerPath", getClass().getResource("resources/PlayerList.xml").getFile());
    String filePath = prefs.get("playerPath", "default");
    if (filePath != null) {
        return new File(filePath);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setPlayerFilePath(File file) {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(GameApp.class);
    if (file != null) {
        prefs.put("filePath", file.getPath());
        // Update the stage title
        //primaryStage.setTitle("Player - " + file.getName());
    } else {
        prefs.remove("filePath");
        // Update the stage title
        //primaryStage.setTitle("Player");
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run the application, it displays the following error message:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   C:\Users\%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80\TowerDefense\TDv2\bin\application\resources\PlayerList.xml
>     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Unknown Source)     at
>   application.util.FileUtil.readFile(FileUtil.java:19)  at
>   application.GameApp.loadPlayerDataFromFile(GameApp.java:242)  at
>   application.GameApp.start(GameApp.java:85)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80\TowerDefense\TDv2\bin\application\resources\PlayerList.xml` exist? :P

Answer (score 0):

First Check your file C:\Users\%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80\TowerDefense\TDv2\bin\application\resources\PlayerList.xml  is exist or not. 
If exist then check it out your file path from jar its proper or not.